# How to create a new dataframe column with shifted values from another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I am returning data from a database query and want to create a new column in the resulting dataframe. I need to shift the results of one column forward one month to create a new column.

I have a dataframe that is populated from a sql query and has the format:

```
df.dtypes
ACTIVITY_MONTH     datetime64[ns]
PRODUCT_KEY                object
COUNT                 float64
```

When I run:

```
df['NEW_COUNT'] = df.groupby('PRODUCT_KEY')['COUNT'].shift(+1)
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

This error doesn't make sense to me and I am not sure what to do to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have duplicate values in your index?

Comment: I don't think so. How do I check that?

Comment: Eg with `df.index.get_duplicates()`

Comment: I do have duplicates. The dataframe is being populated by a loop and then appending those individual dataframes into a master. How do I reindex or otherwise clean them up?

Comment: If the index is not meaningfull, you can just do `df.reset_index(drop=True)` and you will get a new integer range (0..len(df)) index. Otherwise maybe show how you made up the dataframe.

Comment: So I was able to fix it by adding ignore_index=True into the dataframe append statement. Instead of df.append(loop_df) I changed it to df.append(loop_df, ignore_index=True)

Comment: Yep, that is another solution. Does this fix the groupby error?

Comment: It does. Do you want to add that as an answer and I will accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` indicates in this case that you have duplicate entries in your index (and for this reason, it cannot assign to a new column, as pandas cannot know where to place the values for the duplicate entries).

To check for duplicate values in the index, you can do:

```
df.index.get_duplicates()
```

And then to get rid of the duplicate values (if you don't need to keep the original index), you can eg do `df.reset_index(drop=True)`, or you can use `ignore_index=True` in `append` or `concat`.